# DependencyResolver and get service from interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I pass my `IEvent` object then `DependencyResolver` cannot resolve service. Only if I pass concrete object then `DependencyResolver` can resolve service. But I need to pass `IEvent` object, so what I can do?

Here I pass `IEvent` objects:

```
List<IEvent> uncommittedEvents = new List<IEvent> { new NoteCreatedEvent() };

foreach (var @event in uncommittedEvents)
{
    EventBus.Dispatch(@event);
}
```

Here I use `DependencyResolver` - it cannot find service for `IEvent` object (but if I pass `NoteCreatedEvent` it works):

```
public class EventDispatcher
{
    public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent
    {
        foreach (IEventHandler<TEvent> handler in DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IEventHandler<TEvent>>())
        {
            handler.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of my code:

```
public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
}

public class NoteCreatedEventHandler : IEventHandler<NoteCreatedEvent>
{    
    public void Handle(NoteCreatedEvent @event)
    {
    }        
}

public interface IEvent
{
    Guid AggregateId { get; }
}

public class NoteCreatedEvent : IEvent
{
    public Guid AggregateId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

// registration:
kernel.Bind<IEventHandler<NoteCreatedEvent>>().To<NoteCreatedEventHandler>().InRequestScope();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you put the events in a `List<IEvent>`, you lose all compile-time type information. I hate reflection, so I think it's best if you could avoid putting your events in a generic list, and just call your dispatcher directly.

Otherwise, I'd suggest the following changes. Disclaimer, I haven't tested any of this, so it may take a bit of effort to fix any bugs in what I quickly type out here. First, extend your event handlers by providing a non-generic type:

```
public interface IEventHandler
{
    void Handle(IEvent @event);
}

public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> : IEventHandler where TEvent : IEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
}
```

All of your handlers will need to implement the method from the non-generic interface that calls the version from your generic interface:

```
public class NoteCreatedEventHandler : IEventHandler<NoteCreatedEvent>
{
    public void Handle(IEvent @event)
    {
        Handle((NoteCreatedEvent)@event);
    }

    public void Handle(NoteCreatedEvent @event)
    {
    }        
}
```

Then your dispatcher will be something like this:

```
public class EventDispatcher
{
    public void Dispatch(IEvent @event)
    {
        Type genericHandlerType = typeof(IEventHandler<>);
        Type handlerType = genericHandlerType.MakeGenericType(@event.GetType());

        foreach (IEventHandler handler in DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices(handlerType))
        {
            handler.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

If performance is a concern, then you'll want to move the `typeof()` call to a static, so it's only called once per process, and probably want to do caching of the results of `MakeGenericType`. But then again, if performance is a concern, you'd be better off refactoring your code to avoid casting your events to IEvent, so that the compiler can always call the correct `Dispatch<TEvent>` and avoid all reflection. I hate reflection :)